# How to handle different types of OSErros in Python

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, error-code, oserror

So I was coding in a little personal project and I got this problem.

In my code I'm using the basic to open a file.

```
try:
    open(file_name, mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
except Exception as error:
    print("Error while opening/reading the file")
    sys.exit(1)
```

But i want to be able to know if the error is because the file doesn't exists or if I don't have permission to read the file, I don't want to use any string comparison to know that and just wanted to use the Python exceptions to do it.
Looking in the documentation I was able to find that the exception type thrown by `open()` is a OSError and with that you can have multiple exceptions inside this exception (https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError), and here is my question, how can I define it inside a `try/except` if the error is due to low permission or if the file doesn't exists.

Comment: Just changing one thing, I do use the ```error``` variable in the print statement, just forgot to add it on the question :)

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70949475/edit) your question to improve it and add missing details.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle multiple different exceptions by adding additional `except` blocks:

```py
try:
    with open(file_name, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as handle:
        handle.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("file not found")
except PermissionError:
    print("insufficient permissions to open file")
except Exception as ex:
    print("something else went wrong", ex)
```

On a general note, you should use the `with` statement when opening a file to make sure the handle gets released when you're done.